# How to get Node Url in RSS view?

Tags: views, 8, entities, feeds

We are using the default RSS feed view found at `/admin/structure/views/view/frontpage`. We want to change the Show to be Fields so we can setup up which field should be used for the title, link, description, creator, and publication date.

When we attempt to add the node url field we cannot find it. How to add the absolute URL of the node?

We have tried searching for, but cannot find it:

1. Content: Path
2. Node URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called `Link to Content`.

Path field could also be used in older 8 versions (you could construct the full URL with replacement patterns while overwriting the field output).

But the Path field is deprecated in 8.5 and you can use **Link to Content** instead, with **Output the URL as text** option.

Read more here, you can also see screenshots: [Path field deprecation and backwards compatibility for existing views](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2953116).

There is still work being done related to this, and if you get the wrong link in 8.5.1 there is a patch that seems to help: [RSS view with fields give wrong URL from path field](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2673980).

Comment: i don't know why i didn't try that

Comment: Because the wording is different than in D7. It took me a while too to figure out the new ways ;)